# Why Httpclient fails on .NET Core with 401 but work in .NET Framework (and only over VPN)?

Tags: .net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I'm experiencing a weird problem with the HttpClient, which seems to have a different behaviour for NTLM Authentication for .NET Core (3.0 preview 7) and .NET Framework (4.8).

My company runs a TFS in its domain which allows REST calls to be done with NTLM authentication.

As long as the following code snippet is executed from a computer that belongs to the domain (when I'm sitting in the office), it works and I got a 200 response along with the expected json (.NET Core & .NET Framework).

When I'm at home and connecting to my companys network with VPN, the snippet only works when running on .NET Framework, but fails, when it's run on .NET Core, (also works when run from LinqPad).

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler
{
  UseDefaultCredentials = true
};

HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);

// 401 on .NET Core when running "from home via VPN"
var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("http://my-tfs:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_apis/projects");
var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

Console.WriteLine(json);
```

I have already tried adding a credentialCache like this:

```
var uri = new Uri("http://my-tfs:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_apis/projects");

var cache = new CredentialCache
            {
                {uri, "NTLM", CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials},
                {uri, "NEGOTIATE", CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials}
            };

var handler = new HttpClientHandler
{
    UseDefaultCredentials = true,
    Credentials = cache
};

HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);

var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

Console.WriteLine(json);
```

but that didn't help.

I've seen blog entries, that there was a bug with NTLM Authentication in older Frameworks, but apparently, it was fixed in .NET Core 2.1.

Any help on getting this to work without having to specify user/password is appreciated.

Comment: We managed to find a workaround. Go to the TCP/IPv4 properties (maybe v6 for other connections) of the connection and click "Advanced...", in the next window go to the "DNS" Tab and fill out "DNS suffix for this connection" (for me this was "mycompany.local"). With this set, NTLM/Negotiate is working.

Comment: The (un-)funny thing is, as soon as I start up Fiddler to investigate more, it breaks NTLM/Negotiate :-(